# how can I paginate records not by N value quantity, but by created_at.day?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, will-paginate

I have a table `Post`.

Columns: `created_at, title, body`

Default pagination behaviour is to show `n` items per page and than add `link_to prev/next`.

**How can I paginate not by `n` items, but by `created_on` a date?**

I've figured out the gem https://github.com/ankane/groupdate, but it only helps to group, not to do the pagination.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, it sound like you don't want pagination, you want query filtering based on a bucketed value. You will first need a distinct list of post days. You may need to use some database-specific query features to get that from timestamps. For example, with Postgres, you can use the `date()` function to extract just the date portion from your `created_at` timestamp, and we can get a distinct list of them:

```
dates = Post.pluck("distinct date(created_at)").sort
```

Note that this will induce a full table scan, so it'll be slow for a large number of posts.

How you use that list of dates is up to you. You might choose to render a list of them as links for the user to click, for example. You might then have your index method accept a `date` param, then use that to find posts on that date:

```
def index
  scope = Post.all
  if params[:date].present?
    date = DateTime.parse(params[:date])
    scope = scope.
      where("created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ?",
        date.beginning_of_day, date.end_of_day).
      order("created_at ASC")
  end

  # For the given date, paginate the posts on that date in pages of 25
  @posts = scope.page(1).per(25)
end
```

Comment: You can use `where(created_at: date.all_day)` instead of `where("created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ?", date.beginning_of_day, date.end_of_day)`. And the default of order is `asc`, so it can be shortened to `order(:created_at)` too.

Comment: Nice! I wasn't aware of the `all_day` helper. That's a nice addition to the toolbox.